# Need to overlap subarray of a array at particular indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

Generate another array from the following array based on the index supplied thru another array selected.
The following array

```
array =[`0: Array(2)
    0:
      disable: false
      label: "label0" 
    1: 
      disable: false
      label: "label1" 

1: Array(2)
    0:
      disable: false
      label: "label0" 
    1: 
      disable: true
      label: "label1" 

2: Array(2)
    0:
      disable: true
      label: "label0" 
    1: 
      disable: false
      label: "label1"  

3: Array(2)
    0:
      disable: false
      label: "label0" 
    1: 
      disable: true
      label: "label1"]
```

Now, When array `selected = [2,3]`. The disable true data array should be given priority. Then the resultant array should be

```
`0:
  disable: true
  label: "label0" 
1: 
  disable: true
  label: "label1" `
```

Similarly When array `selected = [0,1]`
Then, the resultant should be

```
   0:
      disable: false
      label: "label0" 
    1: 
      disable: true
Edit:label: "label1"
```

Edit : I am sorry I forgot to mention that. So far I have tried following

```js
checked=[2,3]
 arrayData=[
    
    
   [
      {
         "label": "label1",
         
         "disable": true
      },
      {
         "label": "label2",
          
         "disable": false
      },
       
   ],
   [
      {
         "label": "label1",
          
         "disable": false
      },
      {
         "label": "label2",
         
         "disable": false
      },
       
   ],
   [
      {
         "label": "label1",
          
         "disable": true
      },
      {
         "label": "label2",
         
         "disable": false
      },
       
   ]
]
 
const result=this.checked
                  .map(indexAtArrayData => {
                   
                 const element = this.arrayData[indexAtArrayData];
                   const resData=[]
                    if (element) {
                      for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                        resData[i]={label:element[i].label};
 
                        if (element[i].disable || typeof resData[i]['disable'] == 'undefined') {
                            resData[i].disable=element[i].disable;
                        }
                      }
                      return resData;
                    }
                  });console.log(result);
```

I have tried the above code and achieved the result but I am looking for a neater way of doing so.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am sorry. Forgot I am mentioning that.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have updated the code also. Please remove the downvote

Comment: @Lucky i'm trying more clean solution but if you provide the array with this structure would be more helpful `var arr=[[{...}]]`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have updated the code snippet .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a copy of the first wanted array with objects and update `disable` if necessary.

```js
var array = [[{ disable: false, label: "label0" }, { disable: false, label: "label1" }], [{ disable: false, label: "label0" }, { disable: true, label: "label1" }], [{ disable: true, label: "label0" }, { disable: false, label: "label1" }], [{ disable: false, label: "label0" }, { disable: true, label: "label1" }]],
    selected = [2, 3],
    result = selected.reduce((r, i) => {
        if (!r) {
            return array[i].map(o => Object.assign({}, o));                   // take copy
        }
        array[i].forEach((o, j) => r[j].disable = r[j].disable || o.disable); // update disable
        return r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly the selected array represents indices of the original array and at each selected element of the original array you want to select the first element set to disabled and the first element else.

This is how a solution would look like:

```
selectedArray
  .map(indexAtArrayData => {
    const element = arrayData[indexAtArrayData];
    if (element) {
      for (let entry of element) {
        if (entry.disable) {
          return entry;
        }
      }
      return element[0];
    }
  });
```

Comment: It should return all data just that if another index has disable true then the disable true should be updated

Answer (score 0):

```
function processData(arr, selected) {
  let processedArray = [];
  selected.map(index => {
    const element = arr[index];
    if (element) {
      for (let entry of element) {
        let processedEntry = {
          label: entry.label
        };

        if (entry.disable || entry.disable === undefined) {
          processedEntry.disable = true;
        }

        processedArray.push(processedEntry);
      }
    }
  });

return processedArray;
}
```

Here is the link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JokerLOL/0b1ktcjL/19/)